# Table of contents different margins

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I don't know why I have different margins in my table of contents.

It looks like this, and I would like to have all the lines with the same margin.

a

All of those are chapters, and Bibliography ad list of figures are chapters too, so I don't know why it looks like that.

Thank you for your answers.
Sorry for not being very specific.
I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=bibtex, sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}%I use this package to add bibliography and list of figures to the table of contents


\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{}%I use this command to eliminate the numbers of the chapters

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Research}

\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And I get this:
[image]

I would like to have the bibliography at the same level as the other chapters, or viceversa, the chapters at the same level as the bibliography.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: So, do i get this right, your question is: *How to get unnumbered chapters?*

Comment: No, my question is: How can "Bibliography" be at the same level as "Introduction" and "Research" in the table of contents?

Comment: Why are you changing the commands for `chaptername` and `thechapter`?

Comment: See my edited answer. I do not think this would work for `\listoftables` though.

Comment: Note also, that your way created a vertical shift in the chapter title for the numbered chapters.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why.

Comment: Do you know how I can change that too?

Comment: Just kick out the redefinition and use the solution i provided. It does not show the shift.

Answer (score 5):

Set the counter for `secnumdepth` to get unnumbered chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=bibtex, sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{companion}
\chapter{Research}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} works perfect

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` then `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2mm}` in the preambule of your document.

**Edit:** This last answer had nothing to do with the problem apparently. For your problem, defining the heading of the bibliography seems to do the job (at least for the bibliography). Add

```
\defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter{#1}}
```

then `\printbibliography[heading=bibheading]`

and remove the `\addtocontents` line. The MWE is (I had to create a dummy bibliography to have it appearing)

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=bibtex, sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}%I use this package to add bibliography and list of figures to the table of contents

\defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter{#1}}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{}%I use this command to eliminate the numbers of the chapters


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text.\cite{A01}

\chapter{Research}

\printbibliography[heading=bibheading]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works for Bibliography, thanks.
Do you have any clue for list of figures?

Comment: @Oscar You are trying to cure a problem you created. Remove the cause of the problem instead of fixing the issues that arrive.

Comment: @Oscar Edit you MWE to include a list of figures and people will see what they can do.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you think the problem will not appear at all using `\chapter*` with an appropriate number of `\addcontentsline` ?

Comment: Compare the the actual chapter titles and their vertical placement.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.